# Dynamic table layout in Android?

Tags: android

I try to add a table layout from Java code. When there are two fields in a tablerow it displays the first field only. How to display the entire row with all fields?

```
  .....
  ....
  for(int idx=0;idx<4;idx++){
      TableRow tbrow   = new TableRow(this);

      TextView text_v1 = new TextView(this);
      text_v1.setText("TextView");

      TextView text_v2 = new TextView(this);
      text_v2.setText(" Idx : "+idx);

      tbrow.addView(text_v1);
      tbrow.addView(text_v2);

      linearlayout.addView(tbrow);
  }
  .........
      ........
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 5):

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(YourActivity.this);
        ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(YourActivity.this);
    sv.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);

    TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(YourActivity.this);
    tl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tl.setStretchAllColumns(true);

    TextView header= new TextView(YourActivity.this);
    header.setText("This is heading ");
    header.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    header.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#323232"));
    header.setTextSize(17.0f);
    header.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    header.setClickable(true);

    for(int sub = 0; sub <=6; sub++) { // Six Rows will be genrated.
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(YourActivity.this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    if(sub != 0 ){
        TextView col1 = new TextView(YourActivity.this);
        col1.setText("Column1");
        col1.setTextSize(17.0f);
        col1.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 2);
        col1.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        col1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        col1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(50,50));
        tr.addView(col1);

        TextView col2 = new TextView(YourActivity.this);
        col2.setText("Column2");
        col2.setTextSize(17.0f);
        col2.setPadding(0, 2, 0, 2);
        col2.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        col2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        col2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,50));
        tr.addView(col2);

        View v = new View(YourActivity.this);
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1));
        tl.addView(v);
    } 
        tl.addView(tr);// add rows to the table.
     }
        TableRow row1 = new TableRow(Activity.this); // seventh row with //only one column 
        ImageButton startButton = new ImageButton(YourActivity.this);
        startButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        startButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
        startButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        row1.addView(startButton);




row1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tl.addView(row1);

        sv.addView(tl); //add table to scrollview to make it scrollable.
            ll.addView(header); //  add heading to the LinearLayout
            ll.addView(sv);     // add scrollview to LinearLayout
            setContentView(ll);  enter code here
```

Answer (score 2):

this may be useful for you..

```
try
{

    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

    TableLayout tv=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
    tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    int flag=1;

    for(int i=-1;i<jArray.length();i++)
        // when i=-1, loop will display heading of each column
        // then usually data will be display from i=0 to jArray.length()
    {

        TableRow tr=new TableRow(Yourclassname.this);

        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        if(flag==1)
            // this will be executed once
            {

            TextView b3=new TextView(Yourclassname.this);
            b3.setText("column heading 1");
            b3.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            b3.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(b3);


            TextView b4=new TextView(Yourclassname.this);
            b4.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            b4.setTextSize(15);
            b4.setText("column heading 2");
            b4.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            tr.addView(b4);

            TextView b5=new TextView(Yourclassname.this);
            b5.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            b5.setText("column heading 3");
            b5.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            b5.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(b5);


            tv.addView(tr);

            final View vline = new View(Yourclassname.this);
            vline.setLayoutParams(new       
                    TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2));
            vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            tv.addView(vline); // add line below heading
            flag=0;


            }

        else
        {



            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            TextView b=new TextView(Yourclassname.this);
            String str=String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("column1"));
            b.setText(str);
            b.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            b.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(b);


            TextView b1=new TextView(Yourclassname.this);
            b1.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            b1.setTextSize(15);
            String str1=json_data.getString("column2");
            b1.setText(str1);
            b1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tr.addView(b1);

            TextView b2=new TextView(Yourclassname.this);
            b2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            String str2=String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("column3"));
            b2.setText(str2);
            b2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            b2.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(b2);

            tv.addView(tr);


            final View vline1 = new View(Yourclassname.this);
            vline1.setLayoutParams(new                
                    TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
            vline1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv.addView(vline1);  // add line below each row   


        }

    }



}
catch(JSONException e)
{
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```